# ArcGIS javascript api - layer reordering - how to add new layers?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am learning ArcGIS javascript API and wanted to make a reordering panel for my webapp. I looked through the ArcGIS [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/layers_dynamic_reorder.html).

but I'm stuck at `addLake()` function. If I'm understand the sample correctly, to add the new lake layer

```
1. get the existing DynamicLayerInfos from the current map
2. create a new DynamicLayerInfo for the new layer
3. push to the DynamicLayerInfos
4. set the new DynamicLayerInfos to the map
```

The example uses `LayerDataSource` that reference a table as the new data source for the layer.

And how do you add a new layer from a public layer on a MapServer/FeatureServer. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong example. The example you have linked to, deals with reordering layers within a dynamic map service, and not reordering various layers in your JSAPI web app. Which of the two do you want to do?

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [reorder function](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/map.html#reorderLayer) on the map object?

Suppose your map already has 2 layers, and you want to add a new layer in between them, you could use the following code:

```
var LouisvilleLayer=new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(
  "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Louisville/LOJIC_LandRecords_Louisville/MapServer",
  {useMapImage:true});
map.addLayer(LouisvilleLayer);
map.reorderLayer(LouisvilleLayer,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS JS API version 4.22, you can give layer index while adding layer.

```
map.add(layer, 0);
```

The index "0" defines the lowest layer.

[Source](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#add)

Comment: perfect this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

So I still don't really understand the part about LayerDataSource but I did manage to add layer successfully while updating the switchable layered list.

What I did was I used I

1. get the current DynamicLayerInfos from map.
2. generated a new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer of the MapLayer I wanted to insert (remember to use unique id)
3. Add layer to map with app.map.addLayer(...)
4. Then I created DynamicLayerInfos with createDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos()
5. Extract individual DynamicLayerInfo
6. push the new DynamicLayerInfo to the current DynamicLayerInfos list with DynamicLayerInfos.push(...)

Comment: Also, in order for layer to actually reorder on the fly, the Server must provide "Dynamic Layer" service as a "Children Resources". To check if you have Dynamic Layer service enabled, click on a Layer group in your ArcGIS server website. It should say "Dynamic Layer" before the list of layers.